# asp.net mvc and webforms shared authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, webforms

I have few websites based on the WebForms and one based on MVC. All websites have the same settings for forms authentication in web config.

The problem is that once logged in to WebForms website, I have to re-login for MVC websites, but when I log out from MVC website, I am automatically logged out from WebForms websites.

How can I pass information to the MVC website that user was successfully logged in when using WebForms.

Comment: Answer to your second comment is [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28713628/asp-net-webforms-and-mvc-authentication-sharing-via-cookie/28736392#28736392

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this article.  Essentially, you want single sign on.  That is the term to google for.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/SingleSignon.aspx

Comment: Thanks awrigley. This is what I was looking for. The missing part was machine key in my web.config.

Comment: I would like to come back to this issue. I have this working, however, is it possible to have signle sign for two application that use same domain, but are located on different servers? The current situation is, that one app (app1.domain.com) is hosted on iis6, the second app (app2.domain.com) is hosted on the second server on iis7.

Comment: I think you should edit this question, or ask a new, more specific one.  My experience with single sign on is limited to one server, and the solution above is linked to the machine key.  Can two servers have the same key?  I don't know.  I think you should ask the question again and qualify where you have got to.